# How to set default docker environment variables

Tags: docker

I'd like to set the env variable `SERVICE_CHECK_TTL` for all containers by default. Can I somehow use the docker deamon for that like this **broken example of setting a default env variable for all containers**:

> `ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon --env SERVICE_CHECK_TTL=30s -H fd://`

The failing example is part of the docker.service file. The env variable `SERVICE_CHECK_TTL` is used by the Registrator that registers containers in Consul.

EDIT:
I don't want to set this env variable in a Dockerfile or a docker-compose file if there is another way of setting env variables that are the same for all containers (default). The reason is that I'd like to avoid changing every single Dockerfiles and every single docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

The ENV directive in a Dockerfile is designed for that, have a look at the docker docs, they are very good.

So let's suppose all your containers use debian Jessie, you could put in a Dockerfile `FROM debian
ENV xxx yyy`, then build your specific debian `docker build -t mydebian .` and then, when you build your containers, your Dockerfile always starts with `FROM mydebian`
You now have your specific ENV value for all your containers

Of course, you may replace debian by ubuntu, centos or any other

Comment: That's not setting a env variable as default for ALL containers. The Dockerfile-way I have to change every Dockerfile.

Comment: Yes, that's a way to go. However, if it's possible to set an env as default without changing any of our existing images that would be great.

Comment: You can also have an alias for docker run, that adds an `--env xxx=yyy` but I guess this is not what you want

Answer (score -2):

Use this command (remember to change the Docker Host) :

```
docker exec -i CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash -c "export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:port"
```

OR

```
echo 'export DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:port' >> ~/.bashrc
```